# Autoexecute and bind in one step

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, attachment

I have a question: I have a function I want to execute when I call it and to attach an event andler to the function

Now I'm using this solution, but I don't think it's best pratice

```
ff();
$(window).bind('scroll resize', function(){ ff(); });
function ff(){ /* do something */ };
```

What is the best trick for this problem?

Comment: I think your anonymous function that calls the defined function is unnecessary, $(window).bind('scroll resize', ff); ff(); would do the same thing (note that I am not placing () after the ff in the bind step because I want to bind the function called `ff` not the result of `ff()`.  As for tickets I'm afraid I don't know of any

Comment: What is the big deal with calling it yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    function ff(){ /* do something */ };

    $(window).bind('scroll resize', ff ).resize();
```

Comment: This would trigger other resize handlers

Comment: You copied my misstyped closing curly brace ;).

Comment: @Juan Mendes isn't it expected?

Comment: @roasted No, you may have other handlers that you do not want triggered, it may be OK for the OP as it sits, but there could be other handlers and coding assuming there are no other handlers is poor practice asking for bugs

Comment: Be aware that, depending on exactly how the above code is wrapped, `ff()` may fire either once *or twice* on window load.

Answer (score 0):

Well, with window, you could do it this way:

```
$(window).bind('scroll resize load', ff);
```

This triggers the function also on window load.

Comment: This will not work, because I initialize a each cycle that execute functions on window load. Another solution?

Comment: if you don't need to call ff() from any other context other than load, scroll and resize you can always make ff an anonymous function

Comment: It might help to have a better idea of your ff(), is it doing something that can't be called this way?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you want but this is certainly a common pattern.

```
function ff(){ /* do something */ };

...

$(window).on('scroll resize', ff).trigger('resize');
```

By triggering an event, as opposed to calling `ff()` directly, the handler makes a correct interpretation of `this` internally (ie `window` in the example).

Note use of `on()` in preference to `bind()` which is now deprecated.

Comment: This would trigger other resize handlers

Comment: @JuanMendes, yes, this would indeed trigger any other resize handlers attached to the same element(s), which *may* be exactly what is required. If not then events can be namespaced - read about namespacing [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: I do know about namespaced events and that's a better solution than what you have and I would upvote that; however, this is not any better than just calling the function yourself, I'm not sure what the point of the question is

Comment: @JuanMendes, it's not necessarily better to namespace - we simply don't know. And just calling the function is not necessarily an option - see my point about `this` - again, we don't know.

Comment: It is better to namespace since it doesn't assume you want to call all the handlers. The question seems to ask to call the ff function only, not all the attached handlers. If they do want all the handlers to be called, this would be the right answer